# R Filter table with other table(gender table, male or female)

Tags: r, filter

I want to filter score1 table based on gender table. I want 2 output, one is male's score1 and other is female's score1. Here is my work

```
score1.data <- na.omit(students$score1)
```

`score1.data.male <- score1.data %>% inner_join(gender=="Male")`

second line does not work[Here is my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Nj8b.png)

Comment: Try using `filter` something like this: `score1.data %>% filter(gender=="Male")`

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem is that `score1.data` is now a vector. As written it seems what you want to do is actually to filter the data.

1) If you want to keep both male and female, you could split you data with :

```r
split(na.omit(students$score1), score1.data$gender)
```

2) If you really want to subset your data (e.g to get female students) :

```r
subset(x = na.omit(students$score1), subset = Gender== "Female")
```

Comment: First line didn't worked. It throws "operator is invalid for atomic vectors" error. Also second line returns "integer(0)"